# How do I get the redirected url from the nodejs request module?

Tags: node.js, module, request

I'm trying to follow through on a url that redirects me to another page using the nodejs [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

Combing through the docs I could not find anything that allows me to retrieve the url after the redirect.

My code is as follows:

```
var request = require("request"),
    options = {
      uri: 'http://www.someredirect.com/somepage.asp',
      timeout: 2000,
      followAllRedirects: true
    };

request( options, function(error, response, body) {

    console.log( response );

});
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There are two very easy ways to get hold of the last url in a chain of redirects.

```
var r = request(url, function (e, response) {
  r.uri
  response.request.uri
})
```

The uri is a object. uri.href contains the url, with query parameters, as a string.

The code comes from a comment on a github issue by request's creator: https://github.com/mikeal/request/pull/220#issuecomment-5012579

Example:

```
var request = require('request');
var r = request.get('http://google.com?q=foo', function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(r.uri.href);
  console.log(res.request.uri.href);

  // Mikael doesn't mention getting the uri using 'this' so maybe it's best to avoid it
  // please add a comment if you know why this might be bad
  console.log(this.uri.href);
});
```

This will print http://www.google.com/?q=foo three times (note that we were redirected to an address with www from one without).

Comment: You said that the above code redirects three times, how do I know which run is the last iteration?

Comment: It doesn't redirect three times. It prints the URL you were redirected to in three different ways. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @gabrielf, No `this`, because we might use `es6`.

Comment: `res.request.uri.href` will crash if the given url is bad url like 'sdfdsfdgdfgdfgdfg.sdfsdfsdf', so either you can check for `err` or presence of `res` if you want to use this option.

Answer (score 36):

To find the redirect url try this:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
request({ url: url, followRedirect: false }, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(res.headers.location);
});
```

Comment: Ended up here after looking for "don't follow redirects in request in node" so thanks! Wasn't sure how to include that option.

Comment: `res.headers.location` did the job for me.

Comment: May not work as expected if multiple redirects are involved, giving the first redirect rather than the last.

Answer (score 6):

`request` gets redirects by default, it can get through 10 redirects by default. You can check this in the [docs](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback). Downside of this is that you would not know if url you get is a redirected one or original one by default options.

For example:

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.headers) 
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
})
```

gives output

```
> { date: 'Wed, 22 May 2013 15:11:58 GMT',
  expires: '-1',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',
  server: 'gws',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }
```

but if you give option `followRedirect` as false

```
request({url:'http://www.google.com',followRedirect :false}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.headers) 
    console.log(body)
});
```

it gives

```
> { location: 'http://www.google.co.in/',
  'cache-control': 'private',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  date: 'Wed, 22 May 2013 15:12:27 GMT',
  server: 'gws',
  'content-length': '221',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN' }
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

So don't worry about getting the redirected content. But if you want to know if it is redirected or not set `followRedirect` false and check the `location` header in the response.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence "If you want to know if it is redirected set `followRedirect` to `false`"? Wouldn't that stop the redirection process?

Comment: By default you wont get 3xx response because of automatic redirection. So if you wish to know you were redirected/don't want to redirect you must give it as false. It is just for finding out redirection.

Comment: Ask yourself this, were you redirected or not (like in inception) ? you need to know what you are getting is a redirect (aka dreamworld) or direct page(or reality). It is your totem ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you use axios, you can fetch the redirected url like below,

```
 axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        params: {
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.request._redirectable._options.href;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function form for `followRedirect` (rather than `followAllRedirects`), like this:

```
options.followRedirect = function(response) {
  var url = require('url');
  var from = response.request.href;
  var to = url.resolve(response.headers.location, response.request.href);
  return true;
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  // normal code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution [found here](https://groups.google.com/g/phantomjs/c/pYSWP9rFzmQ?pli=1) on Google Groups where is discussed code error corrections from the answer available on [GitHub here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389). This one uses nodeJS JavaScript. Here's the code:

```
var sys = require('system');
var pageUrl = ( sys.args[1] ) ? sys.args[1] : phantom.exit(0);

function forceExit(){
    phantom.exit(0);
}

var renderPage = function (url) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    
    page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
        var tmpUrl = ( url.substr(url.length - 1) != '/' ) ? url+'/' : url;
        var tmpPageUrl = ( pageUrl.substr( pageUrl.length - 1) != '/' ) ? pageUrl+'/' : pageUrl;
        console.log(tmpUrl,tmpPageUrl);
        if (main && tmpUrl!=tmpPageUrl ) {
            pageUrl = url;
            sys.stdout.write(url+'\n');
            setTimeout(forceExit,100 );
        }
    };

    page.open(url, function(status) {
        if ( status !== 'success' ) {
            phantom.exit( 1 );
        } else {
            phantom.exit( 0 );
        }
    },100);

    setTimeout(forceExit,2000 );
};

renderPage( pageUrl );
```