# How to get the redirected URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function change(){
    var clientID = "hgffgh";
    var clientSecret = "fgfhgfh";
    var callbackUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";
    
    var tokenUri = "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token";
    var authUri = "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?"+
            "client_id="+clientID+
            "&response_type=code"+
            "&redirect_uri="+callbackUri

    //var web = window.open(authUri);
    //console.log(web.location.href); 
    
    var win = window.open(authUri, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

    //alert(win)
}
</script>
```

`AuthUri` opens a new window. In new window when I click on allow, I will be redirected to a new window, How to get the last redirected URL?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** You can do that if you can at least declare variables in redirect URL.

---

Before you redirect to the next page, just set "redir" as the redirect page URL (locations.href) in your URL, but encoded as below:

```
"https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?redir=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href)
```

Now, to get the redirect page you need to get the variable "redir" from current URL. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter). So, after getting the "redir", you decode it:

```
var redirectPage = decodeURIComponent(url);
```

Comment: OP doesn't have any control over third party server or access to page code

Comment: @charlietfl How so? There's no code to access. He'll have to parse the URL to get the redirect page.

Comment: When clicks on `approve` a new url is loaded in window... that server isn't going to use your `redir`

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly. The "redir" will continue in the page URL and can be parsed in JavaScript.

Comment: No it won't continue. When the form in that window submits the other server determines the new location. It's that new location that OP wants for some reason

Comment: @charlietfl I see. Anyway, I'll let the answer available if he changes his idea one day or one century.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NodeJS you can do it like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
request({ url: url, followRedirect: false }, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(res.headers.location);
});
```

more info about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687618/how-do-i-get-the-redirected-url-from-the-nodejs-request-module) on this stackoverflow answer

There's also a solution [found here](https://groups.google.com/g/phantomjs/c/pYSWP9rFzmQ?pli=1) on Google Groups where is discussed code error corrections from the answer available on [GitHub here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389). This one uses NodeJs JavaScript. Here's the code:

```
var sys = require('system');
var pageUrl = ( sys.args[1] ) ? sys.args[1] : phantom.exit(0);

function forceExit(){
    phantom.exit(0);
}

var renderPage = function (url) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    
    page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
        var tmpUrl = ( url.substr(url.length - 1) != '/' ) ? url+'/' : url;
        var tmpPageUrl = ( pageUrl.substr( pageUrl.length - 1) != '/' ) ? pageUrl+'/' : pageUrl;
        console.log(tmpUrl,tmpPageUrl);
        if (main && tmpUrl!=tmpPageUrl ) {
            pageUrl = url;
            sys.stdout.write(url+'\n');
            setTimeout(forceExit,100 );
        }
    };

    page.open(url, function(status) {
        if ( status !== 'success' ) {
            phantom.exit( 1 );
        } else {
            phantom.exit( 0 );
        }
    },100);

    setTimeout(forceExit,2000 );
};

renderPage( pageUrl );
```

Answer (score -4):

That is not possible. JavaScript can only get things from its page