# Retrieve redirectUri from npm Request

Tags: javascript, http, npm, request, protractor

I'm trying to retrieve some information from the response that npm Request generated. I'm able to retrieve information like "statusCode" by typing "response.statusCode". However if I want to retrieve other information like "redirectUri", it would show undefined. How am I able to retrieve "redirectUri"?

Below is the code to get the response from the URL that I'm testing;

```
var request = require('request');

var getRequest = function (url, index) {              
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(response.redirectUri);
        });
}  

getRequest('https://www.exampleUrl.com', 1);
```

Below are some of the information from the response;

```
redirects: [
{ statusCode: 302,
 redirectUri:'https://www.exampleurl'.....etc 
}],
```

[Please see the response in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeGfJ.png)
Note: I have blurred out the url that I'm testing.

Comment: You say **Below are some of the information from the response;** -- where is that info coming from? I don't see you trying to access that in your code. Is that part of the data you get from the response?

Comment: @Katie.Sun, the info is coming from the "getRequest" function. I have added the code to call "getRequest" function. Please see above. Yes, "redirects" is part of the data that I'm getting from the response.

Comment: I found my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687618/how-do-i-get-the-redirected-url-from-the-nodejs-request-module. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from [How do I get the redirected url from the nodejs request module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687618/how-do-i-get-the-redirected-url-from-the-nodejs-request-module). Set "followRedirect: false" and use "response.headers.location".

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
request({ url: url, followRedirect: false }, function (err, res, body) {
console.log(res.headers.location);
});
```