# upload and save image from google-drive api node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, image-processing, google-drive-api

I am new to node. I have been digging around trying to find out how to route an incoming image that I am getting from google drives api. I've tried downloading it but it takes to long. I want to be able to send it to the client as soon as i get it. It's probably simple but all I want to do is save it to a png file. . ant help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 app.get("/img", function(req,res){

 https.get(url,function(resp){
   console.log(resp.statusCode);
  console.log(resp.headers['content-type']);
   resp.on("data", function(chunk){
   // I am getting the image raw data  
 .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("public/images/test.png"));
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Your code seems fine?

Comment: I am getting this error.
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("public/images/test.png")); ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe the incoming data directly to a file:

```
resp.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("public/images/test.png"))
```

Youre code will become:

```
app.get("/img", function(req,res){
 https.get(url,function(resp){
        console.log(resp.statusCode);
        console.log(resp.headers['content-type']);
        resp.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("public/images/test.png"));
    });
});
```

Comment: This is putting it in the file but its the entire response. How could I tap into the image only?

Comment: what content-type is the response then? It should be something like image/jpeg

Comment: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: Then this URL isn't an image. Make sure the URL is a direct link to the image, try for example your profile picture: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-poGft7zXvuc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAKWJJOyNllQGCbae8U6WdfKBK4reAVqAA/photo.jpg

Comment: i'm using the shareable link provided from google-drive. If I use
        resp.on("data", function(chunk){
                    res.write(chunk);
            }); I am able to get the image on my page. I just don't know how to direct it to the file.

Comment: That's because a shareable link isn't a direct link to the image but to a webpage.
Can you try to put `&export=download` at the end of the link?

Comment: You should follow the redirect, check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects

Comment: I was able to access it using the download you provided and also with "https://drive.google.com/uc?id="+fileId. It was responding with 302 redirect  I was able to tap into it using resp.headers.location, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687618/how-do-i-get-the-redirected-url-from-the-nodejs-request-module) assigning it to a variable and immediately sending another get request. Everything is now working. I have been on this forever. Thank you for your time and help!