# Get URL of last redirected address NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to get the last redirected address of a LinkedIn address: https://www.linkedin.com/school/18451/?legacySchoolId=18451 which in the browser gives: https://www.linkedin.com/school/babson-college/

In NodeJS, I have tried the following (I have tried all the solutions of [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687618/how-do-i-get-the-redirected-url-from-the-nodejs-request-module)):

```
request({ url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/school/18451/?legacySchoolId=18451', followRedirect: false }, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(res.headers.location);
});
```

But I'm still getting the same initial address (legacySchoolId) instead of the final (babson) one. It seems that the redirect is performed by a javascript function so I was wondering how I could get the last address in all use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and I see two obstacles here:

1) You get the final URL only when you are logged in, otherwise you get a JS redirect to an authwall.

2) The final URL that you see in the browser does not come from a redirect, instead the displayed URL is just rewritten using `replaceState` (HTML5 history API). There is no navigation to a new page there.

I see two options to solve this:

**1) Use a headless browser** like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). Write code to log in with your username and password and then navigate to those URLs, wait a bit (for example until some company info gets rendered) and then read the current URL.

**2) Simulate only the most necessary requests and extract the info from the page** (not sure if it works with LinkedIn though), using a library such as [slimtomato](https://github.com/CherryDT/slimtomato).*  You'd then start by simulating a login with your username and password and then use the same tomato object (or at least the same cookie jar) for the requests to those school links in order to get the final URLs. I didn't find a straight-forward way to see the final URL in the page source, but what would still work in this specific case though is parsing the page for this meta tag...

```html
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=288429040, affiliate-data=ct=campaign_vw_smart_app_banner&amp;pt=10746, app-argument=voyager://school/babson-college/?trk=vw_smart_app_banner">
```

...and then using the `app-argument` value (`voyager://school/babson-college/?trk=vw_smart_app_banner`) without the query and replacing `voyager://` by `https://www.linkedin.com/`.

**: Disclaimer: I wrote that library. But I didn't find a good alternative with the same scope.*