# Finding the final URL that the request will be redirected to in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, request, response

I have the following URL:

```
https://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php?inputstring=95014
```

I would like to figure out which URL it will redirect to. In this example it is:

```
https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=Cupertino&state=CA&site=MTR&lat=37.3042&lon=-122.095
```

I tried multiple solutions such as:

```js
res.headers.location
```

and

```js
res.headers.get('location')
```

But none of them seem to work. I know that the URL redirects because, I could successfully redirect in `curl` and `google-chrome`. Here is the code that I am running:

```js
https.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php?inputstring=95014', res => console.log(res.headers.location))
```

When I was running in `curl`, I ran the following:

```sh
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} http://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php?inputstring=95014
```

And got the desired output of:

```
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=Cupertino&state=CA&site=MTR&lat=37.3042&lon=-122.095
```

When I run `curl`:

```sh
$ curl -I https://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php?inputstring=95014
HTTP/2 302
server: Apache
x-nids-serverid: www1.mo
location: https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=Cupertino&state=CA&site=MTR&lat=37.3042&lon=-122.095
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
cache-control: max-age=722
expires: Mon, 26 Apr 2021 19:28:03 GMT
date: Mon, 26 Apr 2021 19:16:01 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains ; preload
```

As you can see, there are multiple headers present here that are not present inside nodejs's results:

```js
{
  server: 'AkamaiGHost',
  'mime-version': '1.0',
  'content-type': 'text/html',
  'content-length': '288',
  expires: 'Mon, 26 Apr 2021 19:21:50 GMT',
  date: 'Mon, 26 Apr 2021 19:21:50 GMT',
  connection: 'close',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains ; preload'
}
```

I would like to stick to the `http` module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the redirected url from the nodejs request module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687618/how-do-i-get-the-redirected-url-from-the-nodejs-request-module)

Comment: I want to stick with the `http` module built into nodejs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you follow an HTTP Redirect in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323932/how-do-you-follow-an-http-redirect-in-node-js)

Comment: All those answers either use another module or look at the header. For some reason the header is not present in my response even though the URL redirects.

Comment: `https.get` doesn't seem to follow redirects at least by default, so unless it's a 301/302, the response URL should be the requested one.